# Reference one locally defined vue2 component from another

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to set up a reference from one [locally defined](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration) vue2 Component to another like so:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'foo': {template: '<p>Foo</p>'},
    'bar': {template: '<foo />'}
  }
});
```

When trying to render `<foo>` ([see this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/japanuspus/a0gfmvvo/)), Vue (Vue 2.2.1) emits a warning that:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
> component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
> the "name" option.

I have tried to include the `name` option for component `foo`, as suggested by the warning and the section on [recursive components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Recursive-Components) in the guide, but this makes no difference.

Everything works fine if I register the components globally ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/japanuspus/8xndL0mL/)):

```
Vue.component('foo', {template: '<p>Foo</p>'});
Vue.component('bar', {template: '<foo />'});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

Is there a simple way to make the local definitions work, or should I just proceed with globally defined components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bar` doesn't know about `foo`. You have defined things so that your main Vue instance knows about both of them, but it doesn't use `foo`, `bar` does. You need to define `foo` as a component of `bar`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'bar': {
      template: '<foo></foo>',
      components: {
        'foo': {
          template: '<p>Foo</p>'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <bar></bar>
</div>


Vue no longer emits this warning when trying to instantiate "bar":
<code><pre>
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: &lt;foo&gt; - did you register the component correctly?
For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
</pre></code>
```

Comment: Makes sense. I also need to use `foo` from other components, so I guess the solution is to define `foo` globally or assign it to a variable so that I can plug in a reference to it as a subcomponent where I need it.